# How to name each Out-File like each input line from Get-Content?

Tags: powershell

I would like to get the content from each path within pathlist.txt and each path content should be saved to his own pathname.txt file, named like the input path.

So something like this:

```
$pathlist = Get-Content C:\Test\pathlist.txt

$pathlist | % { 
  Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse |
    Out-File C:\Test\Output\"computername_" + $($_.replace("\","_").replace(":","")) +".txt" 
}
```

Input:

- C:\Test\Test\Test
- D:\Downloads
- C:\Windows\Temp

Output:

- computername_C_Test_Test_Test.txt
- computername_D_Download.txt
- computername_C_Windows_Temp.txt

Each output text file contains the result from Get-ChildItem -Recurse for the named path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pathlist = Get-Content ‪C:\Test\pathlist.txt

$pathlist | ForEach-Object { 
  $outFile = 'C:\Test\Output\computername_{0}.txt' -f $_ -replace ':?\\', '_'
  Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_ -Recurse -Name > $outFile
}
```

- I've replaced the multiple `.Replace()` method calls with a single, regex-based call to [PowerShell's `-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).
- I've replaced string concatenation (`+`) with a single call to [PowerShell's format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f), `-f`.
- I've replaced `Out-File` with `>` for brevity.
- I've added `-Name` to the `Get-ChildItem` call so that *path strings* relative to the input path are being output; if you want absolute paths, use
  `(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_ -Recurse).FullName > $outFile` instead (or
  `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_ -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName > $outFile`).

---

As for **what you tried**:

Your problem was that **you didn't wrap the *expression* that built the target filename via string concatenation in `(...)`**, which is necessary if you want to use an expression as a command *argument*.

Note that:

- inside an expression, string literals must be (fully) quoted
- `$(...)` is only needed if you need to wrap *multiple* statements; otherwise, if needed to override standard [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence), use `(...)`.

Thus, your original command could be fixed with:

```
... | Out-File ('C:\Test\Output\computername_' + $_.replace("\","_").replace(":","") + '.txt')
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @matze; my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

it all seems to be ok but there are spelling issues. Try this:

```
$pathlist | ForEach { Get-ChildItem -path $_ -Recurse | Out-File "C:\Test\Output\computername_" + $($_.replace("\","_").replace(":","")) +".txt" }
```

And let me know.